# Condition table based on a value in the joined table

Tags: sql, mysql, join, mysql-8.0

Lets say I have three tables; matches, teams and players, and I want to select all matches where ronaldo or messi has played and then get these matches including all teams and players data not just ronaldo and messi, how do I do that?

I tried:

```
select *
    from
    matches m
        inner join
    teams t
        on t.matches_matchId = m.matchId
        inner join 
    participants p
        on p.matches_matchId = m.matchId
  where p.name = 'ronaldo' or p.name = 'messi';
```

and that returns only messi and ronaldo participants not all players, how do I return all players in those matches but still limit the matches to the ones where messi and ronaldo played.

Comment: And what's wrong with your query?

Comment: it returns only the players specified, instead I want to return all players in those matches, only limit the matches based on messi and ronaldo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the query below.  You basically need to get matches participated by the 2 players, then get the rest of the information.

```
SELECT *
FROM matches m
JOIN teams t ON t.matches_matchId = m.matchId
JOIN participants p ON p.matches_matchId = m.matchId
WHERE m.matchId IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.matches_matchId
    FROM participants  
    WHERE p.name = 'ronaldo' OR p.name = 'messi'
)
```